# How to sort by highest value while building HTML with foreach

Tags: php, html, sql, sorting

I'm trying to create a list of game servers. I want to be able to sort them by the number of players. From high to low.

Here is what I've come up with. However, it just writes them in the order it gets them obviously.

Query:

> ```
>         $sql="SELECT ipaddress, port FROM servers";
>         $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
>             while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
>             array_push($serverArray, ["address" =>$row['ipaddress'], "port" =>$row['port']]);
> ```

Rest:

```
    $server_address = $value["address"];
    $server_port = $value["port"];


    $Query = new SourceQuery( );

    try
    {
        $Query->Connect( $server_address, $server_port, SQ_TIMEOUT, SQ_ENGINE );

        $data = $Query->GetInfo( );
    }
    catch( Exception $e )
    {
        echo $e->getMessage( );
    }
    $Query->Disconnect( );
    ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#one" class="clickable">
                <td><?php echo("$data[HostName]"); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="hiddenRow" colspan="3">
                    <div id="one" class="collapse"><?php echo("$data[Players]"); ?></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

How would I sort them by highest amount of players? Feedback in my current code would be great too. Cheers!

Comment: What does your database query look like? Thats where you specify the sorting method

Comment: @miknik I've updated the post. But I'm not sure that's what you mean. I check each Ip and port that I have in my database to Valves servers to get the players. And I use a library for this, so I don't really know how it actually works.

Comment: Your edit does query for the servers, not for the players. Since you want to sort by the players you need to provide the necessary query. Using `SORT BY Players` at the end of the query might help you.

Comment: @GePu Ah okay, thanks. I don't think I can sort by players in my SQL since I don't know them before the code is run? I'm using this: https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Source-Query/blob/master/README.md

Comment: In this case i would suggest you to store the results in an (multi-)array and [sort it](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).

Comment: Ok. I will thanks for the tips :) I will try to do this.

Comment: This task is best accomplished on the database level.  PHP will be less efficient.  Show us a sample, relevant sql dump of your table that includes the `HostName` and `Players` columns, then we can close this page with the most appropriate link to a pre-existing SO page that shows you how to `COUNT()` and `ORDER BY` to provide a refined and concise resultset.  Help us to help you find the professional-grade solution to your question.

Comment: @mickmackusa I might be wrong, but since I don't have access to the full database with all servers and I have to manually check each to get the info. I don't think I can just do it by sql? I'm using a php library that does this: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code and subsequent comments indicate that whatever database you're querying for the list of servers doesn't know the current player count or list for any given server.

The code you posted just does an array push of the server ip and port. Why not push port twice, with a different name (e.g. Players) so you get another column in your 2D array in which you can store the player count (but at the start it contains port numbers instead), then connect to each server in turn overwriting/filling the players entries in the array, with the actual player counts.. after this you can sort the array and THEN you can output your HTML..

The php docs specifically discuss sorting arrays that came from a database (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) though you might think it easier, once you know how many servers you'll connect to, to declare a separate array for the player counts, populate it in order and then pass both arrays to array_multisort knowing that the second array (servers) will end up sorted in the same order as the player counts one (of player counts is the primary array being sorted)

You'll. need two loops, one to gather the data by connecting each server in turn and getting the player count, then another later on to output

Comment: I forgot to reply to you yesterday. But thank you! This helped me and I managed to do it.

Answer (score 1):

After look through the documentation links:

- https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries
- https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Source-Query

It seems you have to perform iterated queries (though a sort-able batch query would be a fantastic feature).  My suggested snippet below will run the dynamic queries, sort the results (by `Players` DESC, then `HostName` ASC), then display the output in table rows.

Untested Code:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit'],$_POST['checkGame'])){  // check that both expected superglobal elements are set
    // handle non-submitted access
}else{
    $data=[];
    if(!$mysqli=new mysqli('127.0.0.1','username','password','dbname')){
        // handle connection error
    }else{
        if($_POST['checkGame']!='Any'){
            if(!$stmt=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT ipaddress,port FROM servers WHERE game=?") || $stmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['checkGame'])){
                // handle prepare or bind error
            }
        }else{
            if(!$stmt=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT ipaddress,port FROM servers")){
                // handle prepare error
            }
        }
        if(!$stmt->execute()){
            // handle execute error
        }else{
            $result=$stmt->get_result();
            while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
                $Query=new SourceQuery();
                try{
                    $Query->Connect($server_address,$server_port,SQ_TIMEOUT,SQ_ENGINE);
                    $data[]=array_intersect_key($Query->GetInfo(),['Players'=>'','HostName'=>'']);  // only store the two desired elements based on keys from each row
                }catch(Exception $e){
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }finally{  // "finally" is advised syntax @ https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Source-Query/blob/master/Examples/Example.php , ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php
                    $Query->Disconnect();
                }
            }
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }

    if(!sizeof($data)){
        // handle no data generated
    }else{
        /* array_multisort() is better suited than usort().
        // sort result array by number of Players DESC then HostName ASC
        usort($data, function($a, $b) {
            return [$b['Players'], $a['HostName']] <=> [$a['Players'], $b['HostName']];
        });
        */

        array_multisort(array_column($data, 'Players'), SORT_DESC, array_column($data, 'HostName'), $data);

        echo '<div>';
            echo '<table>';
                echo '<thead>';
                    echo "<tr><th>Host Name</th></tr>";
                echo '</thead>';
                echo '<tbody>';
                    foreach($data as $data_row){
                        echo "<tr data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-target=\"#one\" class=\"clickable\"><td>{$data_row['HostName']}</td></tr>";
                        echo "<tr><td class=\"hiddenRow\"><div id=\"one\" class=\"collapse\">{$data_row[Players]}</div></td></tr>";
                    }
                echo '</tbody>';
            echo '</table>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: @Leyer I'd like to see this page be true useful to future visitors (beyond a theoretical solution) Would you please run my suggested snippet and let me know if anything bonks?  If you find any thing wrong or not to your liking, please leave me a comment so that I can fix up my answer.  This question has the potential to help many others in the future.

Comment: I just saw you more recent post, are you going with OOP syntax and prepared statements now?  It is advisable.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've managed to solve it in another way but I will try to run your code when I'm home. Yes I now use OOP syntax and prepared statements.